# Configuration Section Designer Tool - Obtaining XML From Objects

Tags: .net, configuration, configuration-files, config-designer-csd

I am using the CSD tool to create custom configuration sections in my asp.net 3.5 web application.  I have no problem with setting up the section, elements, and collections.  However, when I create new instances of these to represent what I need to persist to the file system, I cannot obtain the resultant XML.  I'm hoping somebody may have ran across this before as well.

An example of the code I'm using that should return the XML is below.  `MyCustomConfiguration` inherits from ConfigurationSection automatically via the CSD generation tool

```
MyCustomConfiguration.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()
```

Sample XML output that should be modeled is below.  The instances I create programatically to model this are perfect but no matter what my output is blank.

```
<myCustomConfiguration ...>
    <friends>
        <name ... />
        <name ... />
    </friends>
</myCustomConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out on my own moments ago.  Turns out I needed to serialize from base rather than the method described above.

```
string test = base.SerializeSection(this, "myCustomConfiguration", ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```